# Insert Date into database table using Zend framework insert method

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, sql-date-functions

I have the foll code as:

```
    $table_project_win = new Application_Model_DbTable_AfterWinProject();

    $data_win = array(
                'project_id' => $project_id, 
                'project_name' => $project, 
                'project_type_id' =>  $pro_type, 
                'start_date' => $dateStart, 
                'end_date' => $dateEnd, 
                'project_size' =>  $size, 
                'project_description' => $pro_des  
    );

    $table_project_win->insert($data_win);
```

Here I get the $dateStart and $dateEnd variabled using as:

```
$dateStartt = $this->_getParam('dateStart');
echo 'date Start: '.$dateStartt;
$dateStart='"'.$dateStartt.'"';
$dateEndd = $this->_getParam('dateEnd');
$dateEnd='"'.$dateEndd.'"'
```

By using getParam I get the value of the date that the user has given input But when i will insert it into the database I use as

```
$dateStart='"'.$dateStartt.'"';
$dateEnd='"'.$dateEndd.'"'
```

But in the database table the value for date inserted is '0000-00-00' While when I echo the $dateStart which I have got through getParam It gives the correct value as '2012-12-11'.What is the reason of it??What Should I do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
replace $dateStart='"'.$dateStartt.'"';
```

with

```
$dateStart= $dateStartt ;
```

or

```
$dateStart='`'.$dateStartt.'`';
```